# PHPMAILER Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed (No Access to Php.ini)

Tags: php, .htaccess, smtp, phpmailer

Good Afternoon,

I've been working on Phpmailer for a couple days and can't get around these SMTP Connect failed errors. I've disabled my firewall and have double and triple checked that my username and password are all correct. I can't access my php.ini file because my server is cloud based (Rackspace). I contacted rackspace and they told me to access my .htaccess file. I however can't find any info on what to add to the .htaccess file to make phpmailer not have an SMTP connect failed error. Code and error reporting is below.  Any and all info is appreciated.

P.S. I also have looked in my php_errors.log file and there are no phpmailer errors in there anywhere!

```
include("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
include("../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
include("../phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host       = "secure.emailsrvr.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->Username   = "xxx@website.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";

$mail->From       = "xxx@website.com";
$mail->FromName   = "xxx";

$mail->AddAddress('xxx@website.com', 'First Name');

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('..contents.htm'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('');

// HTML body
$body  = "Hello";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}else{

    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Error1:

```
2014-12-08 17:35:42 Could not access file:
2014-12-08 17:36:03 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
2014-12-08 17:36:03 SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Error2:

```
2014-12-08 17:38:09 Could not access file: 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp17.relay.dfw1a.emailsrvr.com ESMTP - VA Code Section 18.2-152.3:1 forbids use of this system for unsolicited bulk electronic mail (Spam) 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO everyhome.com 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp17.relay.dfw1a.emailsrvr.com 250-SIZE 75000000 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: cGF1bC5oZWNrQGV2ZXJ5aG9tZS5jb20= 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2014-12-08 17:38:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: S2ltYmVybHkxMTU= 
2014-12-08 17:38:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2014-12-08 17:38:11 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2014-12-08 17:38:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2014-12-08 17:38:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye 
2014-12-08 17:38:11 SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: Are you able to ping and telnet to that host?

Comment: When I ping it just keeps giving me lines of code. It will say   64 bytes from 98.129.229.83: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=48.301 ms, the time will change a little and the icmp_seq=0 will just keep going up one by one

Comment: That's normal behaviour for ping, and it's showing that it's working ok.

Comment: if you don't have access to php.ini on the server, like on most shared hosting system, you can put most of the php config directives on the .htaccess file. I'm not a big fan of putting things on the script, it varies by page, you may miss things on other pages if you do that unless your code is dynamic. its all time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('..contents.htm'), dirname(__FILE__));
                                    ^--- missing /?
```

unless you really do have a "double-hidden" file named "..contents.htm".

As for the smtp error - it timed out. some `secure.emailsrvr.com:465` is firewalled/unreachable from your php server. Since that's not a programming problem, we can't really help you - you'll have to figure out where/how the data packets are getting dropped into the bitbucket.

Comment: Sorry I just changed my original filename to contents.htm when I wrote up the question. It's correct in my file. I guess I'll just have to contact Rackspace again and see if they can help me figure out why it is timing out. Thanks

Comment: fire up a shell and start testing. can you ping the server's address? can you telnet to port 465? if you can't ping or telnet, do a traceroute- where do the packets start dying?

Comment: I pinged and it just keeps giving me lines of code. Almost at 500 lines now and I get my first request timeout on line 360. (Request timeout for icmp_seq 360). I did a traceroute and I can't locate where the packets start dying. I assume where the * are? I'm using terminal on mac by the way

Comment: so yep. something's blocking all packets from your server to that mail server. check your system's firewall, e.g. `sudo iptables -L`. look for drop rules, or chains with default drop policies, blah blah blah. heck, if you want the security risk, just turn off the firewall completely. if you STILL can't get any connectivity then, it's not your server, and it's something upstream of your machine.

Comment: I'll do the sudo iptables -L in one second, but i'm worried because I have already turned off my firewall. I saw that in a couple other forums thinking that was my problem but the firewall has been off the whole time

Comment: then it's something upstream of you and there's pretty much nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: Well regardless thank you for the info and if I find a way around it i'll definitely comment back here saying what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

my php.ini file because my server is cloud based (Rackspace). I contacted rackspace and they told me to access my .htaccess file.?

all you have in your php.ini file is the sendmail config, and you don't have to do anything with .htaccess, that's only if you're going to add things on there as you would on a php.ini file.

you need to look at the maillog. issue

> tailf /var/log/maillog

if you're on the command line to get better debugging message.

---

this would be better if you enabled additional error log

```
require_once '../class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
    $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
    //additional mail related code 

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: I've seen a lot of these errors get solved after people uncommented the ssl line in the php.ini file. I'm a little puzzled on how to look at the maillog issue. How do I go about that?

Comment: checking the maillog on OP's own server is pointless -  the code is trying to connect some OTHER mail server.

Comment: its not pointless because it gives you details that you can't see with naked eye or just by looking at the code. you need the maillog.

Comment: as you modify and make the correction, look at the maillog to see if the messages went through or if they are in a queue.

Comment: Marc B is quite right - if you're sending using PHPMailer's SMTP class (as the OPs code is), there will not be anything at all in the mail server log.

Comment: what is "secure.emailsrvr.com" ? is that an external mail server?

Comment: Apparently so. Much of the point of PHMailer's SMTP support is that it means you don't have to involve a local mail server, which is especialy useful on systems that don't have one, like most Windows servers.

Comment: By not following the docs, your code will not work - you need to load the autoloader, not just the phpmailer class. Otherwise it will not have an SMTP class to work with and it will just fail.

Comment: Isn't "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php" the autoloader?

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a straightforward authentication failure, so please double check your username and password. I suggest starting with one of the examples provided with PHPMailer - this looks like it's based on something pretty old, so also make sure you have latest PHPMailer from github.

Cut down your code to the absolute minimum in order to remove sources of error - for example just set `Body` directly, don't call `msgHTML`, don't load external content, don't add attachments - just cut out everything that's not strictly necessary.

Try connecting using 'tls' on port 587, and you could give `AuthType = 'PLAIN'` a go too. Also confirm that the EHLO response matches the server that you asked to connect to, in case you are being transparently redirected by your ISP.

Checking DNS and network issues is also covered in the [PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).